# Selenium Chrome Driver- Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I am trying to launch the chromedriver with below code . I am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; " error

My code:

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I don't want to put absolute path there, if I put there it will not serve the purpose of reusability.

I have checked and I am sure that chromedriver.exe in the designed path and when I am doing

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
```

I am not sure what I am missing here .. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the question. It says "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property". Not Webdriver! webdriver with a lowercase w!

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I got where is the issue is:

W letter in Webdriver was capital instead of small so below code working for me.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

thanks!